# Vega lite grouped bar chart for time series

Tags: json, visualization, data-analysis, vega-lite, vega

I'm trying to create a bar grouped bar chart for time series data.
There are 2 series, sampled at the same interval. The stacked bar chart looks like this:

[image]

Code: [Vega lite editor code](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemhBQ5mJDVlwATopCY6guGlCY4AD0xaASvtkAzJIMGm2btxDhHVAAmMQBfJR13GjJrEDddLQBJWVsjBQACIzYmNkw2TIgkWQh+AKMaN1MmJCgAazJshlk1LQBiP063AAZu0yQ7Ggg4xvU0TCMGOCVRtQBhNkE2E3Q2gFEAEQAxYK2AdlNzeoWllZA2vYBGAA5ugE4ANlM1NmQDE+X2q9vH00EkJhwQQfM4XG73J5KcyYSwgr7g34REDEGhwZRxNw0LxaZQwESmCATNh1KyrTY7fYgMJI-4AT2MaAA2qBkEY6nFMLScKSQDUTEicEgjEgEMNUMyQLIRTzZgSgXAoEEQAY0sRPNUDK10NBPHBhmEALpKOCyHRqAyxVCgOwAeT8ASCoExQK1Zi5eqpSjsGNRgldaiQtkO7q0tgQOGW6qhFlJsgYXiUAyGcX+gMEAEFZGRLGh+HtukiZEYgnGvEjaT6XVphQYPF4APoIBDB7laACODGK0MDNFIhxjWmgyysicGYuAhb09XGkzgSJ0p0rftD7uGUJD6FkrwMUZAljIJq1NgH6E53P1Sh1OatIBeb3k4u0DCMRhNjkTpGFB5ARpAwqzpKMucAAsTDXAAzJBphtEgbhQNcSDAT+1JQmwizmDgTJOr6-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-dQsMaDDPvntEtQ5Q4F3MEewGwr3RXWt1OVbTati0zWuS1N4HXGI4Rc6T8uhYZt3ow9wsOfTyVW+N2tTcBhlO6HHXh4V-19abnux9tI27Un-utc7wTZ917t55j8fg9bfvNWXGeLRX1254L+fm45Cea01k3NwjYchZXlPKxjqui0XuONwP8ZtS3F1-cZJud5j6vF5Dh3TZcfnl27y3jzH3d14zDf96zYj5pc5ej6vKtez39cl038-7+ZUce7XYNny-28PLveai8kZVxXkfM2546Y-0TlvVm-ljrv2Kp-Guk8N4zwvplPWYhri3w-oDL+k9T4wJtnPMswDw7LSVtHCBIs0F93xjrPWRMh6Z15pcY24Cu6QItr3X2GCU6lRvuQkePUx7UK4bQn258GEtTfsIwy5N+biPXlIv+rNpay3kcjQ+yjCHQPocnI64FLhwxYa3ZaANOEqOngY-23lfIrXLiVKhBDH5ENsbbPW4FOZmIuofZBa9UGqNgZg7BOCtFVyrlYoJNi+EyOhiHXxICwoBIfgXHhz8QkfVCOEpJFCTJ3A7mkk++i4mGJ8ncSpuDTKpInm40p0jk6DxJqwgqJkdGuPSU-X+WTmnc0NnzMRnSSmWw8dve2ADcHsKKXUrpdCymlzkXkthLiUGP3mY0uxbM7imJaa3VaYDdHrOCSQ96fTh5tNdkMtZcyTmzzOUsvZF1FG1OPtwqeOMxnqKDokp5SNs4lWifU0ZCzbaw31hEkyhV76zO7hstRmD-rML+fk+4My3mSNiZszxp0gHLJdnsV5NC44NIRSnO4MtqmEuroE4FvDsWkIXviy6oiYUYqelislhN341LZcSwunzQXbzEA8B4AUtHZyunyiRJKQUMoeWQ5l5NCk0uKe89xQrL5iApeXfx+Cblwrufw+x9tdn9MuWZaV385VkvOa0tuFNVWwvVaS3pjzzXBEoUSmVAqNaap1uBCuPLCX6tpbczlWSTUPGRR65x6L+XewjacnWlSzUXIjpYo5XSNXyswdcSlWjyYcKzYapN9ypYy3TsyquqMgXZtdcmlOVxfkeq9VavRNrI12weAgwtULvXWvpVy6afkfEooGd0aldaRlDq7SK3t1aP5OvZVAztjb7F63Fcyv6hTQ1qpFjm4dx1LhjtbYM5dCaPl+tzQHH5iDeoXp9YmwVN6ElbvHZcwp7bjllv4Xa-ZisB0xJfUewNeKP0ssjo+6xIGu2B2AjG9Ny0p0lvefCudwRrhCMXTnaDHbZ3rp8tGnlmbhloaNfEnyqdwMetWsWsjmLYONv-X4lJe7nWMevcOkV0tdVFQ6Qal1a7y0CJhnxnO7GV0ZJ6YR3yCHqnhUk5e9DzH3Xpr+jdb94amMiZNXcbDEG23TvI7+yjwFAH3vjU+7pxDdM+UMqe9NJVepKes4eudDwII8qUQxjlOnjV2xlgZ2jJlCVadLf5mRLGkZ-UU8Zzjm9ZMPF41ov6PnBMHobXZ8CYgUvbvaVZmDXG4MUpo+ptj8XZUEbs1fIOUzVlhoi8V1TiqIPZ13ZV31iWRPRfDuTOLqGEvoMozxqtEHyaac68+5rNX7bBaQ-xwrwGZsBYQ3sFt6bR6uaK91v9an7XLSiYNvzK3KPwcQ-at2gLjuruqwF7BDwxshY5kBulmSWtMvG-27b+H3t2fM5BHlZkfs-si+U3LOynEFOuY1oTd2RsPF8jylVU2r27ZGyeqHkcQfadO+U+2ewysHaKtd3zXXhvg9MrktroWYf7qq39vbrWz28tRypmror30erdi5tnFHykzTmuJ1aqP3OEd1p6nl9GMsM5k9l8Cus+MoyW29uX93pbU+57TnHM7GcY4XRBv6YXRdZdW9cHt1S3Ym+E0zz7saCs67h3rgX9wuflemeFkzYOtnAWjUT1usXXv1ptyN3Lbv7Wjzw6DvHizmdOYK1H3H6P8cwwu63ZVKvg-w-B2Eqlmfddq6i-t8x2u+emfB94tPF1s5mUT015Pse7fx8jp7zLIeBdK4fdb7PWyvHzcuyTunHGTsN88aZcPAHpl16d4XppxfnlLu7873vEENv2om0PqTNmvmYMR2vgPCel+z62ZBeTkKkGt5HxT3v4-EHS9h23nvniUZPfj8ry-t3l+eJy5rhb3RScy6f7H62zeLrZY7hTT6P5f7CpiqOYR7fZH62a25Y6WqIE74fR3BiD94l45wf7Taj7CpzZQ4X5l7e5j5iAT7V6l43b4HX6vxx4D4Ux4Fo50HCpIrC6b6Xpi41ZpxY7pYP6y5IFnaPDYFUForMHcHIHn4AECFAFCEC4K6iFkz9qQFX7oFHQnRV7JKTpB4F7yG94mKv7E7Y6kEx4gGlbBq6Fe5mHCqYZKF9b9rMHs73bsESp4KmEEEKpN7wFoqqHk7oG9YhR-T3707+H+oByVr1acFuam5F4MHp6LZ+G0HqHTR1apaL40EsEpHBzXC-6MHhQSGxEV7BBwEAa+FoHhGBFLQpKFHt4GFgF9rK5JFZHhFvrVLQoVE3pVGQYQEeGsFaqTLpFIKO5QHAHCqE7+5UHTIjGCEBHz7KE6EzFyHZEG727-5WFDYpGwxBp9rlGZHOEY6lFLysqdHcYIaTHJJNF9FbFByUHaFfrXGtH2YmIKYbFqGVHzFZyDJLHSb6H0HeEJG4anFzoyxHHaEDZk6-HZHeIXHhzLxvHLFPEE6wm8ys6ZGSEja+5po+Ei77H86N7VKoF4nl4EmQq4HAmyZaEOHrHNEYkC5+RGEH4mHolFEn56wokKKD7NEHGU7YJTK1osl1H-HiY3Tcn4meKwxY6kaAHJFPEOIckOoFEUk9afEiLknElkGMrVKHKQnb4fHxHHE0mPGvrTRgY8pKkak2GXzHT75iH8GhGyldGqnVE1I-F6kmkQ4KnLQo6WmeGYKY5uHrFuk8k+5MIkYIlQlPEzTeI8odGClP7Cq5GMmGmTbxnQFwJ7CDH5biHGncb-7YllFxm6khnCnn5Ha6l0k+6lS2naFSq5ldqpzJaIINYOktEmkIaQ67G9G+n9GhJZlfY6Fikkk4pYbVKin1kfbgHRE7a9kfQ2n8n54z5-FanpGOoTn-aaHebTnLZ+kpwcwFmGk15pljGXzFQKnOaLmbFRmzTnlcnKmraE7Jn3Hbmq7LmXyaL5bTHrmrYUo1lwmiK0msk4qlQLnBnikrnZlEkVlAX-y8GNEhHD5hHtl+5Y7G49nQmBxY4tmIWRntnNpTLlkyltm2rOmeonHoVRlUmol1nHlvkVr-7ibdnFngUDH2FqlW4UVOkGnaHYVb6VkgFBY8q8VcEwVwLFR-krKXmzFRkzRekFa1EJnqIIYHkLHCXWYlnby6wQo4aEWyG4XDo5ZiqxkRnuncbBxsUukcXQVCnjIIYSUukhr3kY5GRbmAU2XqJ3B5GAm17fmh65FSkmUaXWkqWopoXMXDmEGYVdkvlZ7pmYK+5PnUlWVEX8XjIOwKl0YxV6FzHcUOEkG0VbFYF3H-nrEKVxURF7yBkdYFX6kAliEQkpWiVoDdEHImWpVeHalZXWG7ndGHZdVXkmkaKJVBG05OEsWYKQReVTFd6cUkW5WolHnhWalwLSwhUjU5k1XtmzRTULHA6+UV6dnMrZypnWWKXNWkXkyLVEVBUBp7BrWclXGbXcZgmhX9XSUekVzFUTo6mNXuU6yXQvUiKPWnXlW9XQ5uVnUYE5YoFvVIXPVGXwVtVNUCK7xK4IVb43UpwoVkkCZ6WmVwZiq3lopgURWXy4qoVSVw1zqV58Gw2OlHr7kcFuntU6yTo7X-lT5OXg7+Ts3rV7VPVdoPAQjNl0342yZ3qrnVVLVWmYLk27E-V42Y1HQWaI0k3LUpoNFHW05Dnq2yLzWXLjkC2Tm7FhW-WQ32IwzDUuw0Ug0nmMJW2Kmi2Y1g0vZjWk3xWa2GbfFc0n66z3WQZXWK3jUpyrWdXM3I0aFNluHDE+2lmfm6WtlK2pH2URwPGzVzr5nI5I1-VNqjmBmB2J3B1lzKRhBAA)

Now, instead of stacking them, I like to create a grouped bar chart as described in the docs:

[image]

The xOffset parameter doesn't seem to like the temporal axis, though:

[image]

The bars are on top of each other instead of next to each other: [Adapted code](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemhBQ5mJDVlwATopCY6guGlCY4AD0xaASvtkAzJIMGm2btxDhHVAAmMQBfJR13GjJrEDddLQBJWVsjBQACIzYmNkw2TIgkWQh+AKMaN1MmJCgAazJshlk1LQBiP063AAZu0yQ7Ggg4xvU0TCMGOCVRtQBhNkE2E3Q2gFEAEQAxYK2AdlNzeoWllZA2vYBGAA5ugE4ANlM1NmQDE+X2q9vH00EkJhwQQfM4XG73J5KcyYSwgr7g34REDEGhwZRxNw0LxaZQwESmCATNh1KyrTY7fYgMJI-4AT2MaAA2qBkEY6nFMLScKSQDUTEicEgjEgEMNUMyQLIRTzZgSgXAoEEQAY0sRPNUDK10NBPHBhmEALpKOCyHRqAyxVCgOwAeT8ASCoExQK1Zi5eqpSjsGNRgldaiQtkO7q0tgQOGW6qhFlJsgYXiUAyGcX+gMEAEFZGRLGh+HtukiZEYgnGvEjaT6XVphQYPF4APoIBDB7laACODGK0MDNFIhxjWmgyysicGYuAhb09TQdYCSJ0p0rftD7uGUJD6FkrwMUZAljIJq1NgH6E53P1Sh1OatIBeb3k4u0DCMRhNjkTpGFB5ARpAwqzpKMucAAsTDXAAzJBphtEgbhQNcSDAT+1JQmwizmDgTJOr6-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-dQsMaDDPvntEtQ5Q4F3MEewGwr3RXWt1OVbTati0zWuS1N4HXGI4Rc6T8uhYZt3ow9wsOfTyVW+N2tTcBhlO6HHXh4V-19abnux9tI27Un-utc7wTZ917t55j8fg9bfvNWXGeLRX1254L+fm45Cea01k3NwjYchZXlPKxjqui0XuONwP8ZtS3F1-cZJud5j6vF5Dh3TZcfnl27y3jzH3d14zDf96zYj5pc5ej6vKtez39cl038-7+ZUce7XYNny-28PLveai8kZVxXkfM2546Y-0TlvVm-ljrv2Kp-Guk8N4zwvplPWYhri3w-oDL+k9T4wJtnPMswDw7LSVtHCBIs0F93xjrPWRMh6Z15pcY24Cu6QItr3X2GCU6lRvuQkePUx7UK4bQn258GEtTfsIwy5N+biPXlIv+rNpay3kcjQ+yjCHQPocnI64FLhwxYa3ZaANOEqOngY-23lfIrXLiVKhBDH5ENsbbPW4FOZmIuofZBa9UGqNgZg7BOCtFVyrlYoJNi+EyOhiHXxICwoBIfgXHhz8QkfVCOEpJFCTJ3A7mkk++i4mGJ8ncSpuDTKpInm40p0jk6DxJqwgqJkdGuPSU-X+WTmnc0NnzMRnSSmWw8dve2ADcHsKKXUrpdCymlzkXkthLiUGP3mY0uxbM7imJaa3VaYDdHrOCSQ96fTh5tNdkMtZcyTmzzOUsvZF1FG1OPtwqeOMxnqKDokp5SNs4lWifU0ZCzbaw31hEkyhV76zO7hstRmD-rML+fk+4My3mSNiZszxp0gHLJdnsV5NC44NIRSnO4MtqmEuroE4FvDsWkIXviy6oiYUYqelislhN341LZcSwunzQXbzEA8B4AUtHZyunyiRJKQUMoeWQ5l5NCk0uKe89xQrL5iApeXfx+Cblwrufw+x9tdn9MuWZaV385VkvOa0tuFNVWwvVaS3pjzzXBEoUSmVAqNaap1uBCuPLCX6tpbczlWSTUPGRR65x6L+XewjacnWlSzUXIjpYo5XSNXyswdcSlWjyYcKzYapN9ypYy3TsyquqMgXZtdcmlOVxfkeq9VavRNrI12weAgwtULvXWvpVy6afkfEooGd0aldaRlDq7SK3t1aP5OvZVAztjb7F63Fcyv6hTQ1qpFjm4dx1LhjtbYM5dCaPl+tzQHH5iDeoXp9YmwVN6ElbvHZcwp7bjllv4Xa-ZisB0xJfUewNeKP0ssjo+6xIGu2B2AjG9Ny0p0lvefCudwRrhCMXTnaDHbZ3rp8tGnlmbhloaNfEnyqdwMetWsWsjmLYONv-X4lJe7nWMevcOkV0tdVFQ6Qal1a7y0CJhnxnO7GV0ZJ6YR3yCHqnhUk5e9DzH3Xpr+jdb94amMiZNXcbDEG23TvI7+yjwFAH3vjU+7pxDdM+UMqe9NJVepKes4eudDwII8qUQxjlOnjV2xlgZ2jJlCVadLf5mRLGkZ-UU8Zzjm9ZMPF41ov6PnBMHobXZ8CYgUvbvaVZmDXG4MUpo+ptj8XZUEbs1fIOUzVlhoi8V1TiqIPZ13ZV31iWRPRfDuTOLqGEvoMozxqtEHyaac68+5rNX7bBaQ-xwrwGZsBYQ3sFt6bR6uaK91v9an7XLSiYNvzK3KPwcQ-at2gLjuruqwF7BDwxshY5kBulmSWtMvG-27b+H3t2fM5BHlZkfs-si+U3LOynEFOuY1oTd2RsPF8jylVU2r27ZGyeqHkcQfadO+U+2ewysHaKtd3zXXhvg9MrktroWYf7qq39vbrWz28tRypmror30erdi5tnFHykzTmuJ1aqP3OEd1p6nl9GMsM5k9l8Cus+MoyW29uX93pbU+57TnHM7GcY4XRBv6YXRdZdW9cHt1S3Ym+E0zz7saCs67h3rgX9wuflemeFkzYOtnAWjUT1usXXv1ptyN3Lbv7Wjzw6DvHizmdOYK1H3H6P8cwwu63ZVKvg-w-B2Eqlmfddq6i-t8x2u+emfB94tPF1s5mUT015Pse7fx8jp7zLIeBdK4fdb7PWyvHzcuyTunHGTsN88aZcPAHpl16d4XppxfnlLu7873vEENv2om0PqTNmvmYMR2vgPCel+z62ZBeTkKkGt5HxT3v4-EHS9h23nvniUZPfj8ry-t3l+eJy5rhb3RScy6f7H62zeLrZY7hTT6P5f7CpiqOYR7fZH62a25Y6WqIE74fR3BiD94l45wf7Taj7CpzZQ4X5l7e5j5iAT7V6l43b4HX6vxx4D4Ux4Fo50HCpIrC6b6Xpi41ZpxY7pYP6y5IFnaPDYFUForMHcHIHn4AECFAFCEC4K6iFkz9qQFX7oFHQnRV7JKTpB4F7yG94mKv7E7Y6kEx4gGlbBq6Fe5mHCqYZKF9b9rMHs73bsESp4KmEEEKpN7wFoqqHk7oG9YhR-T3707+H+oByVr1acFuam5F4MHp6LZ+G0HqHTR1apaL40EsEpHBzXC-6MHhQSGxEV7BBwEAa+FoHhGBFLQpKFHt4GFgF9rK5JFZHhFvrVLQoVE3pVGQYQEeGsFaqTLpFIKO5QHAHCqE7+5UHTIjGCEBHz7KE6EzFyHZEG727-5WFDYpGwxBp9rlGZHOEY6lFLysqdHcYIaTHJJNF9FbFByUHaFfrXGtH2YmIKYbFqGVHzFZyDJLHSb6H0HeEJG4anFzoyxHHaEDZk6-HZHeIXHhzLxvHLFPEE6wm8ys6ZGSEja+5po+Ei77H86N7VKoF4nl4EmQq4HAmyZaEOHrHNEYkC5+RGEH4mHolFEn56wokKKD7NEHGU7YJTK1osl1H-HiY3Tcn4meKwxY6kaAHJFPEOIckOoFEUk9afEiLknElkGMrVKHKQnb4fHxHHE0mPGvrTRgY8pKkak2GXzHT75iH8GhGyldGqnVE1I-F6kmkQ4KnLQo6WmeGYKY5uHrFuk8k+5MIkYIlQlPEzTeI8odGClP7Cq5GMmGmTbxnQFwJ7CDH5biHGncb-7YllFxm6khnCnn5Ha6l0k+6lS2naFSq5ldqpzJaIINYOktEmkIaQ67G9G+n9GhJZlfY6Fikkk4pYbVKin1kfbgHRE7a9kfQ2n8n54z5-FanpGOoTn-aaHebTnLZ+kpwcwFmGk15pljGXzFQKnOaLmbFRmzTnlcnKmraE7Jn3Hbmq7LmXyaL5bTHrmrYUo1lwmiK0msk4qlQLnBnikrnZlEkVlAX-y8GNEhHD5hHtl+5Y7G49nQmBxY4tmIWRntnNpTLlkyltm2rOmeonHoVRlUmol1nHlvkVr-7ibdnFngUDH2FqlW4UVOkGnaHYVb6VkgFBY8q8VcEwVwLFR-krKXmzFRkzRekFa1EJnqIIYHkLHCXWYlnby6wQo4aEWyG4XDo5ZiqxkRnuncbBxsUukcXQVCnjIIYSUukhr3kY5GRbmAU2XqJ3B5GAm17fmh65FSkmUaXWkqWopoXMXDmEGYVdkvlZ7pmYK+5PnUlWVEX8XjIOwKl0YxV6FzHcUOEkG0VbFYF3H-nrEKVxURF7yBkdYFX6kAliEQkpWiVoDdEHImWpVeHalZXWG7ndGHZdVXkmkaKJVBG05OEsWYKQReVTFd6cUkW5WolHnhWalwLSwhUjU5k1XtmzRTULHA6+UV6dnMrZypnWWKXNWkXkyLVEVBUBp7BrWclXGbXcZgmhX9XSUekVzFUTo6mNXuU6yXQvUiKPWnXlW9XQ5uVnUYE5YoFvVIXPVGXwVtVNUCK7xK4IVb43UpwoVkkCZ6WmVwZiq3lopgURWXy4qoVSVw1zqV58Gw2OlHr7kcFuntU6yTo7X-lT5OXg7+Ts3rV7VPVdoPAQjNl0342yZ3qrnVVLVWmYLk27E-V42Y1HQWaI0k3LUpoNFHW05Dnq2yLzWXLjkC2Tm7FhW-WQ32IwzDUuw0Ug0nmMJW2Kmi2Y1g0vZjWk3xWa2GbfFc0n66z3WQZXWK3jUpyrWdXM3I0aFNluHDE+2lmfm6WtlK2pH2URwPGzVzr5nI5I1-VNqjmBmB2J3B1lzKRhBAA)

Any tips on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many data points. Adding the timeunit:month achieves this:

[image]

```
 "x": {
          "field": "date",
          "type": "temporal", "timeUnit": "month",
          "title": null,
          "axis": {"labelAngle": -70},
          "sort": null
        },
```

Or this:

[image]

```
   "x": {
          "field": "date",
          "type": "temporal",
          "timeUnit": "month",
          "title": null,
          "axis": {
            "tickCount": 8,
            "labelAlign": "left",
            "labelExpr": "[timeFormat(datum.value, '%b'), timeFormat(datum.value, '%m') == '01' ? timeFormat(datum.value, '%Y') : '']",
            "labelOffset": 4,
            "labelPadding": -24,
            "tickSize": 30
          },
          "sort": null
        },
```

Comment: Thank you Davide! Specifying a timeUnit helps a lot indeed! I'm not too happy to throw away granularity. This rainfall data is in intervals of 10 days, so called "dekads". When I use `"timeUnit": {"unit": "dayofyear", "step": 10}` this comes close and I'd consider it not too many points. I notice with your nice looking `labelExpr` the year seems off. 2012 and 2013 do not reflect the actual data. Do you know why?

Comment: I think the parsing isn't working correctly. Try "timeUnit": "yearmonth", and it looks correct to me. Don't forget to mark as solved and upvote if you found the solution useful.